# strtok Invalid read of size 1

Tags: arrays, c, char, file-handling, strtok

I am reading in a text file as a `char` array and separating up the values by the space separator using `strtok` and placing each separated word into its own sub array in `inputArray`.

This runs fine in CLion however if I compile via command line, I get the error `invalid read size 1` (Valgrind). I have read that the end of the string needs to be null terminated for `strtok` to work which I thought I had implemented?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *read_string(const char *filename) {
    char *buffer = 0;
    long length;
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb"); //was "rb"

    if (f) {
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell(f);
        fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        buffer = (char *)malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
        if (buffer) {
            fread(buffer, sizeof(char), length, f);
            buffer[length] = '\0';
        }
        fclose(f);
    }

    return buffer;
}

int main() {
    char *inputFile = read_string("input file.txt");
    char *inputFile3 = read_string("input file.txt");

    // counts the number of characters in the file to determine size of array to create
    int count1 = 0;
    for (char *p = strtok(inputFile, " "); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        count1 += 1;
    }

    char *inputArray[count1];

    // creating array of words
    int l = 0;
    for (char *p = strtok(inputFile3, " "); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        inputArray[l] = p;
        l++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Supposing that `read_string()` successfully opens the file, and the file is not empty, and the `malloc()` call succeeds, yes, it returns a pointer to a null-terminated buffer.  Otherwise, it returns a null pointer, which your `main()` neglects to test for.

Comment: If you compile with debug information then Valgrind will give you more informative messages about where the invalid read occurs.

Comment: At seems awfully wasteful to read the file twice.  I understand why you're doing that, but there are better ways.

Comment: How would I test for a null pointer @John Bollinger

Comment: Null pointers are falsey, @ben, (and all other pointers are truthy) and null pointers compare equal to each other.  So `if (!inputFile) { /* handle inputFile is null */ }` works, and `if (inputFile == NULL) { /* handle inputFile is null */ }` is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the error is that you run the program from a directory which does not contain the `input file.txt` file.

Consider adding error handling for the case when the file cannot be opened and `if (f)` condition is not satisfied. In this case `read_string` returns NULL, this error should be handled by the caller to tell the user that the file is not found.

Comment: I added a test for this and the condition is satisfied in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your program does not have proper error handling: the `main()` function should test if reading from the file succeeded and report the failure with a proper message.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *read_string(const char *filename) {
    char *buffer = NULL;
    long length, nread;
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb"); //was "rb"
    if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n",
                filename, strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell(f);
    if (length < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot seek in %s: %s\n",
                filename, strerror(errno));
        fclose(f);
        return NULL;
    }
    fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = (char *)malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        fclose(f);
        return NULL;
    }
    nread = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), length, f);
    buffer[nread] = '\0';
    fclose(f);
    if (nread != length) {
        fprintf(stderr, "read %ld bytes instead of %ld\n", nread, length);
    }
    return buffer;
}

int main(void) {
    char *inputFile = read_string("input file.txt");
    if (inputFile == NULL)
        return 1;
    char *inputFile3 = strdup(inputFile);
    if (inputFile3 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory: %s\n",
                strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    // counts the number of characters in the file to determine size of array to create
    int count1 = 0;
    const char *sep = " \t\r\n";
    for (char *p = strtok(inputFile, sep); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, sep)) {
        count1 += 1;
    }

    char *inputArray[count1];

    // creating array of words
    int i = 0;
    for (char *p = strtok(inputFile3, sep); p != NULL; p = strtok(NULL, sep)) {
        inputArray[i++] = p;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count1; i++) {
         printf("%s\n", inputArray[i]);
    }
    free(inputFile);
    free(inputFile3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @chqrlie, though I am afraid that I am still getting the same error as before.

Comment: @ben: do you get any other output before the valgrind error message?

Comment: nope @chqrlie ...

Comment: @ben: you can try adding extra `fprintf` calls to output the file length and the words as they are parsed... this may help you track down where the error occurs and in what circumstances.